# Button (images) aren't appearing for firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I have setup my website and put the images for the buttons in the correct place I believe I have used the right method to make it so across all browsers even mobile they appear properly. But for some reason now I am having an issue with people using firefox and on phones it is actually showing up the icons are a little too big and proportionate because the website was design for a widescreen.

Is there any way to fix this for firefox and mobile phones?

Source code: https://pastebin.com/xfsXHuTt

I believe it has something to do with this area, I am not sure.

I just  can't seem to get them to fit properly.

```
@media (min-width:320px)  {
    #store{
            content:url("http://website.com/store.png");
            width:35vw;
            height:35vw;
            max-width:100%;
            vertical-align:middle;
            text-align:center;
            display:inline-block;
            }
```

Comment: You are required to post your code and markup here, not your web site or other third party which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future: [mcve] Your web site is horribly invalid on top of  that missing the fundamentals of modern web pages.

Comment: I was  only posting it for people to test and see whats wrong... @Rob

Comment: To repeat: you are **required** to **post here** a **minimal, complete and verifiable example**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is usually used for pseudo classes(before/after).

Why don't you use the background-image property throughout? It is needed that you specify the background-size as well. Because you have already specified the width & height, you can use 'contain' as background-size.

what background-size:contain does

> Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its
>   height can fit inside the content area

So the code you posted would become:

```
@media (min-width:320px)  {
    #store{
            background-image: url("http://website.com/store.png");
            background-size: contain;
            width:35vw;
            height:35vw;
            max-width:100%;
            vertical-align:middle;
            text-align:center;
            display:inline-block;
            }
```

Comment: His markup is thoroughly broken at the top and beyond help at this time.